# What are these characters Ö and Þ supposed to be and how do I configure firefox to load them properly?

Tags: firefox, fonts, linux-mint

tl;dr: My internet browser is not configured properly so characters are not loading properly. I am using the default Firefox 24.0 in Linux Mint 16, and have not installed any typesetting software. I am doing a math test and I am getting unusual characters. Ö and Þ are being displayed, but I think a √ and ⇒ should be displayed instead, respectively. What do I need to install to get these to load properly.
I know very little typesetting software and I am technologically inept.

I am currently doing an online math test. There are four tests that I need to do. If I exit the test, it will automatically submit whatever answers I have selected.

The test I am doing right now is a very easy basic algebra test, about middle school level. All the questions on it are true or false questions. To illustrate how easy the test is supposed to be, the first question is asking if the following statement is true or false:

a/(a/b) = a/b

After this, I am getting unusual characters in the questions:

|-7|=Ö49=7

Ö8-Ö29=Ö(-21)

Ö8-Ö29=-Ö21

3x=6 Þ x=2

(x-2)(x+2) = 1 Þ x-2 = 1 or x+2 = 1

Based on how they are being used, I assume Ö should be a √, and that Þ should be a ⇒

Am I correct?

What do I need to install to get these to display properly on future tests? The course's section on the university website does not specify what needs to be installed, but it recommend using Internet Explorer or else there's a chance that "fonts will not load properly".

I asked this in tex but they sent me here.

Unfortunately, I cannot link the problem page as only people in my program can view it.